# RMI interface loading

Tags: java, rmi, classloader

Have a question related to how RMI loads the interface classes.

So here is my set up:

An interface that defines the operation that the rmi server performs.

### Common

```
public interface Computable<T> extends Remote{
    public AnalyticalServiceOutput<T> compute(Request request) throws RemoteException;
}
```

### Server

```
Computable<Map<String, String>> stub = (Computable) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 0);
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2000);
registry.rebind("myservice", stub);
```

### Client

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, port);
Computable c = (Computable) registry.lookup("myservice");
AnalyticalServiceOutput<Map<String, String>> output = c.compute(request);
```

For deployment, I put the common jar in the classpath for client as well as server.

When I ran the client and server on eclipse, it worked perfectly fine.
Feeling triumphant, I moved both the client and the server to a linux box.
But now, when I make a call to compute(request), the client complains (ClassNotFoundException) that one of the classes defined in the common is not available.

Any ideas as to what is going on.

Cheers

Comment: Is the common Computable class available on the classpath at both the client and server?

Comment: Yes. It is available on the classpath.

Also, FYI, I am starting the rmi registry from the server using
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2000);

Answer (score 0):

Your class "AnalyticalServiceOutput" must either implement interface Serializable or extend Remote. If the client and the server are on different machines the result must be transmitted by wire and this can only be done with serializable classe or remote objects (where the proxy stub is transferred).